# Why does use of a variable in a lower scope change how a variable is resolved in a higher scope?

Tags: python, scope, disassembly, cpython

I have a trivial function that returns its argument, and the value is obtained using cpython's `LOAD_FAST` instruction.

```
def function1(n):
    return n  # LOAD_FAST for n -- what I expect

dis.dis(function1)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (n)
              2 RETURN_VALUE
```

However, adding a lambda expression to the function body results in the value being obtained using `LOAD_DEREF`.

```
def function2(n):
    return n  # LOAD_DEREF for n -- this is surprising
    lambda: n  # LOAD_DEREF for n -- what I expect

dis.dis(function2)
  2           0 LOAD_DEREF               0 (n)
              2 RETURN_VALUE

Disassembly of <code object <lambda> at 0x..., file "...", line 3>:
  3           0 LOAD_DEREF               0 (n)
              2 RETURN_VALUE
```

Why does the lookup of `n` change in the higher scope depending on whether `n` is used in a lower (dependent) scope?